# Get document ID with CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, csom

I'm using the following code to get a document via its documentid in a ASP MVC application:

```
...
// Get Document ID
ctx.Load(uploadFile, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
documentID = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Id;
...
```

This seems to work fine, but not in combination with the Sharepoint Document ID Service. I have the following prefix: Sales00(docID) for all documents, but the CSOM only returns the docID.

> http://sharepoint/subsite01/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=(document_id)

If I include a link in my MVC application like above it shows the id as in '81' and not as 'Sales0081'. How to retrieve the correct value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Site Collection Feature Document ID Services, when activated generates a Unique ID for a Document. The format of this ID is something like `PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68`.

In your question you have specified a URL in which you are passing a query string value `document_id`. I am not sure what value you get in it, and how you get it?

I am sure about 2 things

1. You should not pass the usual IDs like `81` in URL `http://sharepoint/subsite01/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=(document_id)`
2. You must pass the actual Document ID which is generated by Doc ID services, which is looks like `PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68`. So your URL becomes `http://sharepoint/subsite01/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68`

You get the Doc ID from the List Item Object something like below.

```
...
// Get Document ID
ctx.Load(uploadFile, f => f.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
documentID = item["_dlc_DocId"]
...
```